# How to instal addictive key with cubase 5

Tags: keyboard, midi, usb, cubase

A recently got a version of cubase and addictive key from a sound engineer of my company.

So I installed cubase OK

When i instal addictive key it ask me  for "stand alone" "32bit" "64bit" ?
So i installed addictive key 64bit and stand alone

My master key board is connected to the computer by midi/usb cable

Cubase see it OK
Addictive key see it OK

In both the sound is processed OK

BUT I can't get to make cubase recognize addictive key as a plugin ?
it is not in VST instrument, and nowhere to be found in cubase onfiguration menus ?

Did i miss something ?

If anyone know what could be the issu, or know where i can find th installation procedure for using cubase+addictive key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the version of cubase your running is only 32 bit, in which case you cannot run the 64 bit version as a VST. Try installing the 32 bit version and see what happens.

Comment: correct, cubase 5 is only 32 bit

Comment: oh that was the solution thanks, i forgot this post

Answer (score 1):

> When i instal addictive key it ask me for "stand alone" "32bit"
>   "64bit" ? So i installed addictive key 64bit and stand alone

Possibly, the stand-alone version is disabled from being a VST (non stand alone)? Try installing as non-stand-alone and seeing what happens. I know it's a pain to do that but at least you'll find out.

Comment: srry i forgot to accept the other answer. The problem was with 32/64bit versions. But thanks for the answer anyway